# Powershell script to obtain first-level subfolders size and save results in a CSV

Tags: powershell

Looking to adjust the code contribution from http://woshub.com/powershell-get-folder-sizes/ and save results in a CSV file.

The Powershell cmdlet gci works fine:

```
gci -force '\\sqlserver\users$' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ? { $_ -is [io.directoryinfo] } | % {
$len = 0
gci -recurse -force $_.fullname -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | % { $len += $_.length }
$_.fullname, '{0:N2} GB' -f ($len / 1Gb)
}
```

But I'm doing something wrong when:

- reading a text file containing a list of servers;
- saving the output in an array to export the CSV as in the code below:

I've adjusted as showed below, but the .CSV output is empty

```
#Starting array
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$resultsArray = @()

#The base path we want to use will be set here
$basePath = 'sql$'

#Import the servers from a text file
$servers = Get-Content -Path "C:\tools\servers.txt"

foreach ($server in $servers) {
    
    $curPath       = $null
    $result        = $null

    #This will be the path we pass to the module
    $curPath = "\\$server\$basePath"

        Write-Verbose "Working with [$curPath]!"
    
    $result =  {
        gci -force $curPath | ? { $_ -is [io.directoryinfo] } | % {
        $len = 0
        gci -recurse -force $_.fullname | % { $len += $_.length }
        $_.fullname, '{0:N2} GB' -f ($len / 1Gb)
        }
        }
         
        #Add our result object to the array
        $resultsArray.Add($result) | Out-Null
        
}   
#Example of exporting combined results as CSV

#Flatten array
$combined = $resultsArray | ForEach-Object {$_}

#Export combined array
$combined | Export-Csv -Path .\result-share-size.csv -NoTypeInformation -Force

#Return results array
return $resultsArray
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please update your question to describe the expected result and how the actual result differs, including any error messages.

Comment: At first glance your issue is here `$curPath = '\\$servers\$basePath'` the single-quotes are not allowing variable expansion.

Comment: And that needs to be `$server` (the iterating variable), not `$servers` (the collection)

Comment: Adjusted $curPath quotation and iterating variable. same results.

Comment: `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` is preventing you to see the actual issue then.

Comment: There is no `$resultsArray.Add(...)` in addition to previous comment.

Comment: Removed ```-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue``` and included ```$resultArray.Add```, but it seems there's a problem with the variables and the output contains the gci command itself

Comment: I recommend taking this to the PowerShell subreddit for help. There's too many issues to fix on SO which is intended to answer specific directed questions. For example, your extra brackets around the `$result` code is returning a ScriptBlock, not an array. Youre retuning your results like `'Value1','Value2'`, but you need to return an object with attributes. You can use `gci -Directory` instead of using a filter to check types and I'm questioning your usage of `-Force` on `gci` and whether it's necessary. And I'm not sure why you need to flatten the array, PS often is able to skip this.